# Обработка .ogg на Python

Tags: python, ogg

Есть необходимость переформатировать .ogg в .wav.
Используя модуль soundfile получаю ошибку:

> Error opening 'audio.ogg': File contains data in an unimplemented format.

Погуглив, понял, что проблема в кодеке, мой файл закодирован кодеком opus\или какой-то другой, а библиотека работает только с vorbis.
Как перекодировать в другой кодек?

Comment: Через ffmpeg может?

Comment: https://pyogg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @Эникейщик , читал про нее, но не нашел там как решить свою проблему((

Comment: @Эникейщик вернее сказать, скорее не смог разобраться, чем не смог найти решение..

Comment: @eri решил командой 'ffmpeg -i audio.ogg -vn output.wav'